# Guild Member Add does not work (discordjs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I have a code where if someone joins the bot gives a welcome message but when a user joins, the bot does not give the welcome message.

Code:

```
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {

    const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "general")
    if (!channel) return;

    const joinembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`A new member just arrived!`)
    .setDescription(`Welcome ${member} we hope you enjoy your stay here!`)
    .setColor("#FF0000")

    channel.send(joinembed)
});
```

My bot has all the permissions and is at the very top of the role hierarchy, please help I don't know what am I doing wrong. This problem also applies when the user leaves (It also does not give the welcome message)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Discord made some changes a few days ago. The bot is not sending the welcome message because it never gets the `guildMemberAdd` event. From now on to get these types of events you will have to turn the intents on in the [dev portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications). After doing this your code will start working again.

[image: dev portal]

Comment: Did you get that working? Because it's not working for me and I've done that.... =]

Comment: @taxilian make sure you are requesting those intents on bot startup too. The PHP discord bot uses the ```getDefaultIntents()``` which excludes the presence/guild members intents ```return static::getAllIntents() & ~(static::GUILD_MEMBERS | static::GUILD_PRESENCES | static::MESSAGE_CONTENT);```

Comment: Yeah I made some changes to how I was initializing things and now it's working for me, but I'm not actually certain what I changed. I thought I was doing that before =]