# Welcome message not sending through Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

So I am coding a discord bot with discord.js and one of the features is that when a new user joins the server the bot sends a message. I am not making it an embed for now, I can do that myself later.

Here is my main `welcome.js` file specifically made for this feature:

```js
module.exports = (client) => {
    const channelId = '868192573011931185' //welcome channel
    client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
        console.log(member.name)

        const message = `Hello <@${member.id}> and welcome to ${guild.name}! 
        Please verify through the Server Captcha Bot in your DMs, 
        then read the rules in <#868192573263605884> 
        and lastly pick your roles in <#868192573263605880>!`

        const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
        channel.send(message)
    })
}
```

And in my `index.js` file I just imported the file, and added `welcome(client)`.

But for some reason my code is not showing up in the Welcome channel... Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Events should not be in a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your intents are open and check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64618047/guild-member-add-does-not-work-discordjs) for further information:

Comment: That worked thanks, I also had to change ${guild.name} but that worked thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the context of your `index.js` but I suggest reading through this handy guide where they explain how you can handle events in seperate files.

Basically they loop through an `events` folder(where your `welcome.js` would be).
Then they dynamically register the events that the `client` object receives to execute through those event files.

Link: [Event handling.](https://discordjs.guide/event-handling/)

Answer (score 0):

In your code, instead of saying

```js
const channel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId)
```

**try say:**

```js
const channel = Client.channels.cache.get(channelId)
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: I thought it would, but still it didn't send any messages :(

Comment: @PrezOfTheUnitedIdiots there is a chance you dont have your server member intents on, go to the dev portal and turn it on and see if it works :)